# How to see opened cmd running at batch script when it is scheduled to run using windows scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I've written batch script and added that in windows scheduler service.

It runs fine and I can access my deployed app which I'm deploying using that service but I want command promote to get open and see that command running when that service is in progress.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you add your batch script in the question.

Comment: set location=C:\MyProjectLocation
set svn=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
"%svn%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%location%" /closeonend:2
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Build-All -DskipTests;Deploy-All;

Comment: Start a program of windows scheduler contains:- C:\MyProjectLocation\mybat.bat